# Export from Lightroom cc15 without original files

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-5, export

Hi I’m new to this community and I was hoping someone could help me.

I have Lightroom on an old computer I’d love to export some of the pictures but I have no idea where the originals are. I’m fine with exporting them with the adjustments I’ve made in Lightroom.

When I try to export Lightroom pops up an error saying original files can not be found.

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have the originals you will only be able to extract the preview images, which will be of lower quality. Adobe has a script which can do the extraction [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/extract-previews-for-lost-images-lightroom.html). Adobe notes that

> The extracted previews don't contain any metadata from the original image. (And)
>    The extracted previews don't contain an ICC profile. So, if you import the extracted previews back into Lightroom, the images are imported with the sRGB profile.

Comment: It’s amazing. They took the time to write a script for the process instead of just baking it into the software.

Comment: Thank you. I only need the pics for online so it should be ok.